# Prove that exists an $M\in \mathbb{N}$ that $|f(z)|\leq \frac{c}{|z|^{m}}$ for some $c>0$ with certain conditions (f holomorphic function)

Tags: complex-analysis

If

1. f is an holomorphic function for $|z|>R$,
2. $\lim_{z\rightarrow +\infty }\,  f(z)=0$,
3. $f$ is continuous in  $|z|=R$,

prove that there exists an $M\in \mathbb{N}$ that 
$$
|f(z)|\leq \frac{c}{|z|^{m}}\:\text{ for some }c>0.
$$

I tried with $z=1/w$ and I'm trying to work with something like [this](http://math.arizona.edu/~tgk/520a/hmwk2_sol.pdf)  (problem 2) to prove that, but I don't know how to write it formally.

Comment: show what you attempted

Comment: I tried with z=1/w and I'm trying to work with something like this https://www.math.arizona.edu/~tgk/520a/hmwk2_sol.pdf (problem 2) but I don't know how to write it formally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $w=\frac{R}{z}$ and $g(w)=f(z)$, and one gets g holomorphic in the open unit disc (first in the punctured unit disc and then by removing the isolated singularity at the origin by hypothesis 2), continuous on the boundary, $g(0)=0$, so there is an integer $m \geq 1$, s.t. $g(w)=w^mh(w)$ with $h(0)$ non-zero (actually any lesser $m \geq 1$ will do, but this one is the maximal one that works), so $h(w)=\frac{g(w)}{w^m}$ is continuous in the closed unit disc (and analytic in the open disc but we do not really need that), so in particular h is bounded by some constant A on the closed unit disc. So $|g(w)|\leq A|w^m|$ in the unit disc and translating back to $f$ and $z$, we get $|f(z)|\leq \frac {AR^m}{|z^m|}$ for $|z| \geq R$, hence taking $c=AR^m$ we are done. As noted any lesser m works too as long as it is at least 1, by adjusting the constant, but the one above is maximal under the hypothesis. Analyticity is crucial in two places - removing the singularity and the existence of m